# IOS: How to delete the default translucency effect of navigationbar?

Tags: ios

I want to display a full screen background image, but the navigationbar is translucent. I tried to set a transparent backgroundcolor,  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
yourNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```